# MongoDB not updating in node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update my database within the node.js app but it's not working. I console.log'ed the parameters and they are being shown correctly (i.e. brand, size, and user email are all valid and defined). How do I make this work?

Function within controller that's being called:

```
var User            = require('../models/user');

exports.addToFavs = function(req, res) {
    var user=req.user; 
    var brandToFind = req.body.brand;
    var size_result = req.body.size; 
    var email_user = user.local.email; 
    //res.send? local.email?
    User.update({local: {email: email_user}} , {$set: { $push: { favorite_shoes: { brand: brandToFind, size: size_result}}}} , {multi : true}, function(error) {
        if (error) console.log(error);   
        console.log('Added %s with size=%s', brandToFind, size_result);
        console.log(User.find(email_user)); 
        res.redirect('/favorites');
    })
};
```

Schema:

```
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    }, 
    favorite_shoes : [shoeSchema],
    history: [searchSchema],
});

var shoeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    brand: String, 
    size: String, 
}); 

var searchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    brand_original: String, 
    brand_result: String, 
    size: String,
});
```

Comment: I don't use mongoose, however your shoeSchema and searchSchema should be before userSchema, because `favorite_shoes : [shoeSchema]` is pretty much `favorite_shoes : [undefined]`

Comment: I did that, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one glaring problem in your find and potentially another. This bit is wrong:

```
User.update({local: {email: email_user}}, ...
```

And it's wrong because of the way you are specifying this it is looking for a document with `local` that [**exactly**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#exact-match-on-subdocument) matches what you are querying. In other words, looking for a document that does not also have a `password` field in the sub-document as well. What you want is:

```
User.update({"local.email": email_user}, ...
```

That **will* match an `email` field in the document with the matching value, regardless of what additional fields are in the sub-document. For more information, give the manual section a good read, until you are familiar with the various query forms.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

The second *potential* thing that may not be immediately evident from the code you have posted is related to your use of Mongoose. It's a trap for the un-initiated and those still *thinking in relational* terms.

You show your **schema** definitions, but unless you are using only **one** model (just for `User`) then the operation you are trying to do will **not** work. The reason is, that in the single model form, then your related schema are considered to be [embedded documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) that are suitable for the update operations you are doing.

If you have however defined a model for each of `shoeSchema` and `searchSchema`, these documents will actually get created in separate collections and this type of update will not work.

In the latter case, go back to the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.8.x/index.html), get acquainted with the concepts, re-think and implement your logic again.